# Why my "ll" command does not run in one account, but runs in another account?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I haven't used Linux for many years and I've never been a sys admin, now I need to setup one account just like the other. I have root privilege.

I have 2 Ubuntu 14.04.2 accounts : *13 and *14

On *13 it's set up so that if I type `ll`, it will mean `ls -alF`, and it's saved in a file called `.bashrc`

But on *14, it won't recognize `ll` even though I've manually copied the `.bashrc` from *13 to *14, but I did a search online, and found if I do: `. ~/.bashrc`, then `ll` will work on *14 just like on *13.

But if I logout and log in again, it won't work again, I'll have to do `. ~/.bashrc` again.

So my question is, what do I need to do so on *14, it can behave just like on *13, where I can use `ll` right after I login and don't have to do `. ~/.bashrc` first?

I have no idea how these accounts are setup, they are corporate accounts in another city and they just gave me access to play with them, so I can test out some stuff. But I do have root access, so I guess I can change things if necessary, but I just don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Is your shell set to something other than *bash* on *14?

Comment: How are you logging in to these accounts to test this? `.bashrc` is read by the shell automatically for all interactive non-login shells. Are you perhaps testing a login shell versus a non-login shell?

Comment: Show output of `alias ll`.

Comment: Since I am not familiar with Linux, I have no idea, how to find out and how to set *14 just like *13 ?

Comment: For the copy on *14 is it owned by the right account so that it can be run at startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My `.bash_profile` script starts with this preamble:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
# . . .
```

I think bash might only source the `.bashrc` for certain types of shell sessions. Check if you have something similar to the above in your *13 account. Maybe adding that to the `.bash_profile` on your *14 account will fix the problem.

Comment: There is a ".profile" file in *13, and it has something like what you said, so I copied it over and login again into *14, now it works, thanks !

Comment: Documented in detail in the bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files